# Symfony2 - How do i set the entity manager that the controller createForm function uses?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I have a Form Type that uses a query builder with an entity field to get related options. But because I am using a custom entity manager for the entity it doesnt seem to recognize those options. And i get the error:

```
Entities passed to the choice field must be managed. Maybe persist them in the entity manager?
```

The controller action:

```
/**
 * @Route("/edit/{keyword_rank_id}/", name="lg.keywordrank.campaign.edit")
 * @Template
 */
public function editAction(Request $request, Company $company, $client_slug, $keyword_rank_id)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($company->getEntityManagerName());
    $client = $this->getEntityOrNotFound($em, 'LGClientBundle:Client', 'client_slug', $client_slug);
    $kr = $this->getEntityOrNotFound($em, 'LGKeywordRankBundle:KeywordRank', 'keyword_rank_id', $keyword_rank_id);
    $form = $this->createForm(new KeywordRankForm(), $kr, array('client'=>$client,'em'=>$em));
    ...
}
```

And the Form Type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('name','text',array(
        'label'=>'Campaign Name'
    ))
    ->add('client_domain', 'entity', array(
        'class' => 'LGClientBundle:ClientDomain',
        'choices'=> $this->getClientDomains($options['em'], $options['client']),
        'property' => 'domain',
        'label' => 'Domain: '
     ));
}

private function getClientDomains($em, $client)
{
    $domains = $em->getRepository('LGClientBundle:ClientDomain')->findBy(array('client'=>$client));
    return $domains;
}


public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'LG\KeywordRankBundle\Entity\KeywordRank',
        'client' => null,
        'em' => null
    ));
}

public function getName()
{
    return 'lg_project_keywordrank';
}
```

Anyone have a similar issue or know how to resolve this would be great

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can specify the entity manager to use when you add a field:

```
->add('client_domain', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'LGClientBundle:ClientDomain',
    'choices'=> $this->getClientDomains($options['em'], $options['client']),
    'em' => $options['em'],
    'property' => 'domain',
    'label' => 'Domain: '
 ));
```

This option takes the entity manager name, not the option itself, so you have to change

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager($company->getEntityManagerName());
```

into

```
$em = $company->getEntityManagerName();
```

Check out the doc here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#em

Comment: Thanks, not sure how i missed that in the documentation XD.

Comment: Yeah i needed the answer fast so it was worth it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my app and in fact if I pass entity manager instance to form it works.

In my case the issue was rather in config.yml file and I wanted to solve this globaly.

I have as default entity manager, "mymodule" but in FormType was used different entity manager.
This was my configuration

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: mymodule
    entity_managers:
      mymodule:
        auto_mapping: true
        connection: mymodule
        mappings:
          AppBundle: ~
          XBundle: ~
```

When I changed default_entity_manager to default in my config file:

```
orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    default_entity_manager: default
    entity_managers:
      default:
        connection: mymodule
        mappings:
          AppBundle: ~
          XBundle: ~
```

and I changed in my controller:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('mymodule');
```

to:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('default');
```

It works without passing entity manager to FormType so in my case it's about orm entity manager configuration.